# Working on Android Frame Animation Programmatically

Tags: android

I have some frames of images(like a progress bar filling a glass of water), in which I am setting duration programmatically according to user and I am doing frame animation programmatically like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allDrawables.size(); i++) {
        FrameAnimation.addFrame(allDrawables.get(i), millisecond);  // allDrawables is a list of all drawables, FrameAnimation is an object of AnimationDrawable
    }
FrameAnimation.start();
```

The Problem is I am getting milliseconds in float values, But addFrame function only takes int values which is causing accuracy problem in my animation!

```
addFrame(drawable,int); // I want float values in place of int
```

> How to run frame animation more accurately by setting float decimal values of milliseconds to each frame?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Why would you need fractions of milliseconds anyways? Will a user really notice that your frame is some fraction of a millisecond too long or too short?

Comment: filling of glass with water according to selected values... :(

Comment: from where you are getting milliseconds ?

Comment: My point is no human can discern fractions of a millisecond. Screen refresh rate is 60Hz, meaning 60 frames per second--that's about 16 milliseconds per frame. Even if you could specify fractions of a millisecond in the duration of a frame, it would be useless.

Comment: the problem is every frame is letting some fraction of millisecond skip and they all evolve in one great piece of millisecond that is causing accuracy issues !

Comment: @RajeshSharma so copy the source of AnimationDrawable and modify it to match your needs